# Discolored ComplexPlot ColorFunction

Tags: plotting, color, complex

I have this code.

```
ComplexPlot[
  z,
  {z, -1 - I, 1 + I},
  FrameLabel -> {"Re[z]", "Im[z]"},
  ColorFunction -> (Hue[#8 / (2 Pi), 1, 1]&),
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False
]
```

When `z` is the first argument of the `ComplexPlot` function, it (somewhat) works as intended.

[image: 1]

But, when I change the expression to a single value rather than `z`, such as `1`...

[image: 2]

...the red is less saturated than it should be. I set the color function to `Hue[#8 / (2 Pi), 1, 1]&`. `#8` is `Arg[1]`, which is `0`. So this should be computed as `Hue[0, 1, 1]`: [image: 3]. But this is not the color we see. Why is anything but the hue of this plot being manipulated? For that matter, why do the colors get less saturated as they get farther from 0 on the `z` plot? And how can I prevent all of this?

P.S. For whatever reason, `0` and `Infinity` are the only numbers plotted as pure red as they should be. In fact, infinities of all arguments are still plotted as red, even though their arguments are not zero.

Comment: You have to consider the `sfunc` as well. If you don't want it to mess with the shading, set it to `None`: `ColorFunction -> {Hue[#8/(2 Pi), 1, 1] &, None}`

Comment: That would be this question's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting my comment as an answer:

> You have to consider the `sfunc` as well. If you don't want it to mess
>   with the shading, set it to `None`: `ColorFunction -> {Hue[#8/(2 Pi), 1, 1] &, None}`

More information about `sfunc` is in the documentation.